# Add attributes with XElement

Tags: xml, vb.net, xelement

I have a file xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<svg version="1.1">
<g ID="Prova1"/>
<g ID="Prova2"/>
</svg>
```

I need to add some attributes in the nodes 
For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<svg version="1.1">
 <g ID="Prova1" onclick="prova()" />
 <g ID="Prova2" onclick="prova()" />
</svg>
```

Where the id is null i don't do something.
I use VB.net and class XElement

Comment: You have to use `XAttribute`.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try

```
Dim someXE As XElement = <svg version="1.1">
                             <g ID="Prova1"/>
                             <g ID="Prova2"/>
                         </svg>

For Each xe As XElement In someXE.Elements
    xe.@onclick = "prova()"
Next
```

Comment: @Fabio - don't understand your comment.

Comment: I liked that you used `XML Literals` - specific property of VB.NET

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim xml As String = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" & _
                            "<svg version=""1.1"">" & _
                            "<g ID=""Prova1""/>" & _
                            "<g ID=""Prova2""/>" & _
                            "</svg>"
        Dim element As XElement = XElement.Parse(xml)
        For Each g As XElement In element.Descendants("g")
            g.Add(New XAttribute("onclick", "prova()"))
        Next g
    End Sub

End Module
​
```